# Enabling Smart Card Readers on Windows 10 Pro?

Tags: windows-10, smartcard

Windows 10 Professional will not natively allow for using a Smart Card for a sign in option. Does anyone have any ideas on how to enable this, like a 3rd party option, or a group-policy edit, IDK?

It is available on Win 10 Ed. and Win 10 Enterprise, however, they are not Windows 10 Pro. This is not a question for concern on making a P.C. more secure, this is mainly for a niche project more than anything.

Comment: Smartcard authentication is really an enterprise-scale thing. For personal use, you might want to look into U2F (IIRC) instead.

Comment: @DanielB Thank you, security is not really my concern. It is more of: I have the ability, and I am quirky. Thank you, though. That is interesting, so, I will have to look into it. Especially if a card is available and not just a USB drive, and, provided, I can use the card reader I have.

Comment: So you're asking what you need to do to be able to read smart cards?

Comment: @fixer1234 I updated the question